# Get value from information page Opencart

Tags: opencart

How can I get the data from information page to a controller to display content of the information page.
like I put content "Hello World" then how can I get this in xyz.php controller in catalog.[image]

Comment: where you want to display admin or front ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get data of information module in your own controller, here the way :

**In Admin**

you have to load information model in your own controller file. by using following code

```
$this->load->model('catalog/information'); // load model 

// to get all the information module data
$results = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformations($data= array());
```

**In Front end**

```
// load controller
$this->load->model('catalog/information');

// get information data    
$information_data = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformations();
```